# MongoDb initial startup says hot fix not installed but it is

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to install MongoDB on Windows 7 Enterprise (32bit) VM running in VirtualBox on Windows7 Ultimate 64bit.

The MongoD.exe start up reports a missing Microsoft Hotfix, KB2731284. I downloaded and installed the hot fix on the VM. The hotfix was not required on the Host PC.

Mongod.exe still reported it was not installed. Ran the hotfix a second time and it reported that it was already installed.

I tried uninstalling an reinstalling mongoDB, no luck.

Stuck, any ideas?

MongoDB.com lists stackoverflow as the support portal.

Comment: This very tag summary [tag:mongodb] lists [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) as the place to ask database admin and configuration questions. Your MongoDB questions on StackOverflow should be "programming based" as that is what StackOverflow is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30502253/5919473)
I think you can run MongoDb without applying the Hotfix, but I would not recommend it. In long time you may run into problems. They have included some fixes in MongoDB to workaround the problem.

On Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 when applying the hotfix you get a better file allocation performance what is relevant for MongoDB

So when using mongo 2.6.0 there is workaround implemented.